# Как реализовать кастомный ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне нужно сделать точно такое же вью как на скриншоте отмечено красной линией

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я начал искать как сделать такую реализацию в `ListView`, но наткнулся на реализацию в `StackPanel` как тут

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFL4XoS627I

и это меня запутало немного. Из моего опыта(не связанного с wpf) я бы делал это в `ListView` с помощью кастомных вью, но нет много времени разбираться как правильно это сделать в wpf поэтому решил спросить как правильно сделать такую имплементацию?

Comment: https://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/UI_WPF/level22/22_1.php

Comment: Наверно можно вовсе использовать `DataGrid`, там даже есть `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.